# error: variable has initializer but incomplete type c

Tags: c

I made this:

```
typedef enum {NOT_SELECTED=0, EASY, NORNAL, HARD, GODMODE} difficulty;
```

and yet,  when I used the command:

```
enum difficulty mode= NOT_SELECTED;
```

It showed it was an error. Help?

Comment: You need to write `difficulty mode= NOT_SELECTED;` or `enum difficulty {NOT_SELECTED=0, EASY, NORNAL, HARD, GODMODE};`

Answer (score 3):

Since `difficulty` is a `typedef`, you shouldn't put `enum` before it when declaring a variable using that type. It should just be

```
difficulty mode = NOT_SELECTED;
```

A `typedef` is used in declarations just like built-in types, you don't need to put anything before it.